# Find the pattern and fill in the question mark

Tags: knowledge, visual, pattern, lateral-thinking

[image: Three circles with some portions shaded red along the circumference, and a question mark]

Hint:

> Hg

Hint 2 (added later):

> What is a common use of hint 1?

Hint 3 (added later):

> °

Hint 4 (added later):

> The red arcs in the top left and top right cover the same angle.

Comment: Did you create this puzzle yourself, or find it somewhere?

Comment: I created it myself using GeoGebra.

Comment: Great! Just checking because sometimes people post puzzles here that look like this (just an image, not much context) because they found it somewhere and got stuck solving it. I guessed yours wasn't like that, as you mentioned aligning the circles yourself, but wanted an explicit confirmation.

Comment: Fair enough :)

No guarantee the idea is unique, but it's obscure enough that I couldn't find it anywhere on Google or this stack.

Comment: Does the red arcs in the bottom left cover exactly half the circle, or slightly less, or is it irrelevant ?

Comment: @Evargalo As it turns out, it's exactly half the circle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elaborating on @gsomani's answer,

> The three diagrams show the range of temperatures with liquid water in standard pressure conditions according to three different [temperature scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_of_temperature), as angle measures:
>  - Celsius (0-100°) on the top left
>  - Kelvin (273-373°) on the top right
>  - Farhenheit (32-212°) on the bottom left

Logically, the figure in the bottom right must be

> the same representation for another scale of temperature. There are various options (Réaumur, Newton, centigrade...) but the most probable should be the [Rankine scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine_scale), with a red arc going from 492° to 672° (i.e. for a half-circle from 132° to 312°).

Indeed, in that way:

> There are 2 scales starting at the absolute zero and 2 that don't, and 2 scales where degrees have the same amplitude as °C and 2 where degrees have the same amplitude as °F.

Answer (score 9):

> The red part in top image shows temperature in centigrade scale and bottom image shows temperature in fahrenheit scale. In the left images, temperature show is (0-100)°C in top and (32°-212°)°F.

> The right image has red arc ranging from (-87 to 13)°C in top circle

**Update**:
After the hint by @cap and OP,

> Top Right is the same temperature range in Kelvin scale(273-373)K.

Comment: Nice. Given hint 4, I'm thinking the top-right is [rot13](https://rot13.com/)(Xryiva sbe gur fnzr enatr)...

Comment: Very close, but the final answer isn't right. See comment from @cap which more or less completes the answer, if you want a spoiler.

Comment: Yep, update is correct. So what goes in the question mark?

Comment: @gsomani If you add the rest of Evergalo's answer to your solution, I'll accept this instead since you were first.